# Passing variable to BigQueryInsertJobOperator via xcom_pull

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, jinja2, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a simple DAG that should execute a SQL query and pass the result of the query as a variable to the next task that inserts some data into BQ.

My code looks like this:

```
def get_sql():
    client = bigquery.client()
    query = "SELECT path FROM TABLE limit 1"
    result = client.query(query).to_dataframe()
    result_values = f"% include '/test/folder/{result['path'].values[0]}' %"

    print(f"{result_values=}") ###airflow log shows the correct path to the sql file i.e. /test/folder/myfile.sql

    return result_values

execute_sql_file = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id = "execute_file"
    configuration = {
        "query": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_sql') }}", ### this line producess the error
        "useLegacySql": False
    },
)
```

This code fails with "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'get_sql'. Can somebody please advise how to proceed here?

Is there a alternative approach to be used for executing a sql file based on a result from the previous task?

Cheers